# An empty lock to guarantee thread completion

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

My c# service looks like this:

```
public partial class MyService : ServiceBase 
{
    private object @lock = new object();
    private CancellationTokenSource cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private Timer timer = new Timer(Worker, null, 0, 20*1000);

    private void Worker(Object stateInfo)
    {
        lock (@lock) {
            if (cancellationSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                return;

            //code that must not execute after OnStop

        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        cancellationSource.Cancel();

        lock (@lock) {}

        //Worker is guaranteed not to execute any more code here
    }

}
```

As you can see, Worker should not run any more code after OnStop, and I think the empty lock sorts that out, since even if the Worker enters the lock after it, it will immediately exit, due to the cancellation token.

However I have never seen an empty lock, so I'm concerned I missed something. Did I?

Comment: I don't think this will do what you want. If you are already in the lock in Worker then you will just have to wait for the lock in `OnStop`. It won't take the lock away from Worker or anything like that. I think you need to go and read up on how locks work. I guess it will mean that nothing will run in worker after `OnStop` returns but I don't know if delaying `OnStop` is really what you want...

Comment: @Chris That's exactly what I want - it should wait until Worker is finished. What I need is that when OnStop returns, and services.msc shows my service as Stopped, I can be sure that Worker is not running.

Comment: Ah, then maybe that will do what you want though I am not sure if there are better ways of doing it.

Comment: Why can't you remove the `lock`? It serves no purpose here.

Comment: @PatrickHofman So that when OnStop exits, I can be sure that Worker is no longer running.

Comment: Looks fine to me, though I also never seen lock to be used like that. But on the other hand - after you cancelled your token, how can worker perform any more work even without locks?

Comment: @Evk Lets say Worker takes 10s to execute, and OnStop is called after 5s - without the lock, OnStop would exit immediately, while Worker would continue for another 5s.

Comment: So indeed, seems fine for me.

Comment: You can add a `CountDownEvent` here, all your workers will add `1` to that event, and after `OnStop` called you simply prevent other workers to add ticks for it. After that you simply wait for it to became `0` and that's it, workers finished.

Comment: @VMAtm `simply prevent other workers to add ticks for it` - how would I do this in a thread safe manner?

Comment: Some simple boolean flag with `Volatile` class reads

Comment: @VMAtm Won't work - let's say I do `if (!stopped) countDown.AddCount()` - maybe `!stopped` was executed before `OnStop` and `AddCount` after.

Comment: If you do it with `Interlocked`, you always get fresh value.

Comment: @VMAtm I don't understand how to use `Interlocked` here. Please add an answer with all the code needed, and if it is a viable alternative, I will accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `lock` serves no goal here. What you are trying to achieve can be done better by using `Task`:

```
Task.Run(Worker, cancellationToken);
```

If the timer is hit, the cancellation token will immediate stop the task from running further.

Comment: I don't want to abort the Worker in the middle.

Comment: That is what your code says. You don't want to let that code run after a certain point. So what is it what you want then?

Comment: That OnStop should wait until Worker is finished. If stopping using services.msc, you will see Stopping... as long as Worker is running.

Comment: Then put all worker `Task`s in a list and `Task.WaitAll(tasks);` in the `OnStop`.

Comment: How do I put a Worker triggered by a timer in a list?

Comment: Instead of putting `Worker` in the timer, put in another method where you start a task. Then add that task to a list.

Comment: That won't work. Let's say the timer ticked, but hasn't yet put the task in the list, and then OnStop is called.

Comment: And how exactly would you ensure the tick gets executed? What if the program terminates before?

Comment: If the service terminates, eg by Windows shutting down, OnStop will be called first, which will cause ticks not to be executed, thanks to the line `if (cancellationSource.IsCancellationRequested) return`.